# Is it possible to combine all of these into one foreach?

Tags: c#, foreach, controls, parallel-foreach

So far I've tried var and couldn't get it to work. 
Code:

```
var a = new { drives1, ipAdd1, spotify1, timeAndDate1, activeWindow1, reminders11, weather1 };
```

And then foreach (Control/var c in a) and get errors, And I'm sure there has to be a simple way without all the code below.

---

Current Code:

```
        foreach (Control c in drives1.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Name.StartsWith("SC")) { c.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rr, gg, bb); }
        }
        foreach (Control c in ipAdd1.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Name.StartsWith("SC")) { c.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rr, gg, bb); }
        }
        foreach (Control c in spotify1.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Name.StartsWith("SC")) { c.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rr, gg, bb); }
        }
        foreach (Control c in timeAndDate1.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Name.StartsWith("SC")) { c.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rr, gg, bb); }
        }
        foreach (Control c in activeWindow1.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Name.StartsWith("SC")) { c.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rr, gg, bb); }
        }
        foreach (Control c in reminders11.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Name.StartsWith("SC")) { c.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rr, gg, bb); }
        }
        foreach (Control c in weather1.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Name.StartsWith("SC")) { c.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rr, gg, bb); }
        }
```

Comment: You could do a Lambda expression, which removes the Loop.  But you would need to an expression for each different object.
You could put the expression in a single method and then pass each controls object into the method.
Then that would reduce code duplication.

Comment: are you using Winforms? what type are all the objects : `drives1, ipAdd1, spotify1, timeAndDate1,...`?

Comment: @MongZhu: additionally , are they have any common parent?

Comment: They're all UserControl's, but because of how I've added them to the Winforms it doesn't show up under UserConrol

Comment: it seems odd to control this kind of logic this far from the controls themselves. it might be a good idea to ask yourself if that logic belongs where you are trying to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least you can get it working with 2 foreachs:

```
var a = new List<ContainerControl> { drives1, ipAdd1, spotify1, timeAndDate1, activeWindow1, reminders11, weather1 };
foreach (var container in a) {
    foreach (Control c in container.Controls)
    {
        if (c.Name.StartsWith("SC")) { c.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rr, gg, bb); }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are initialising an anonymous object, over which one cannot iterate. your code as posted here will not compile.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I meant it to be a List type but didn't changed the code. I'll fix it now.

Comment: This code was the best, Nice and short thank you for your help, Marked Correct :) Again thank you.

Comment: Thanks for @TimothyGroote as well for pointing out my initial mistake :)

Comment: also props to @Mong Zhu for pointing out that the collection initialiser allows you to do this!

Answer (score 1):

If all the item in `a` have a common super class which define `Controls` then you can aggregate all the controls, filter the one you need and then iterate it:

```
var allControls = a.SelectMany(i=>i.Controls.Where(c=>c.Name.StartsWith("SC"));

foreach (var control in allControls)
{
    c.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rr, gg, bb);
}
```

If not, then you can use `union`

```
var allControls = drives1.Controls
    .Union(ipAdd1.Controls)
    .Union(spotify1.Controls)
    .Union ...
    .Where(c=>c.Name.StartsWith("SC");
```

Answer (score 1):

> They're all UserControl's,

Then create a `List<UserControl>` as collection. This way you specify the common data type and the compiler will not complain. It will Then loop through it:

```
List<UserControl> a = new List<UserControl>{ drives1, ipAdd1, spotify1, timeAndDate1, activeWindow1, reminders11, weather1 };

foreach (UserControl uc in a)
{
    foreach (Control c in uc.Controls)
    {
        if (c.Name.StartsWith("SC")) { c.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rr, gg, bb); }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

if you look into the inheritance hierarchy of the class `UserControl` in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

[image]

you will find that 2 levels above it inherits from the [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) class which has the property [Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx) that you are using in your loop. So `UserControl` is the lowest common ancestor that you can use for your collection.

Comment: does the list initialisation in your example work like that? (i.e, wouldn't it really be a `List<List<UserControl>>`)?

Comment: @TimothyGroote yes it does, code compiles and works, just tested it again to be sure

Answer (score 0):

Add a method:

```
private void SetColor( List<Control> control)
{
    foreach (Control c in control)
    {
       if (c.Name.StartsWith("SC")) { c.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rr, gg, bb); }
     }
}
```

iterate over a:

```
foreach (Control c in a)
{
   SetColor(c);
}
```

Comment: you could move the `if` statement in your first code example into the `foreach` selector with linq

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
private static void Edit()
{

   setForeColor(drives1.Controls);
   setForeColor(ipAdd1.Controls);
   setForeColor(spotify1.Controls);
   setForeColor(timeAndDate1.Controls);
   setForeColor(activeWindow1.Controls);
   setForeColor(reminders11.Controls);
   setForeColor(weather1.Controls);

}


private static void setForeColor(Controls controls)
{
        foreach (Control c in controls)
        {
            if (c.Name.StartsWith("SC"))
            { 
                c.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rr, gg, bb); 
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: I found this to work with a bit of tweaking, the post below this one worked best, with fewer lines, Thank you for your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can join them into a single IEnumerable then use a where condition to get the matchers:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1 {

    public class Control {
        public Control(string name) {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var list1 = new List<Control> { new Control("a"), new Control("b"), new Control("c") };
            var list2 = new List<Control> { new Control("a"), new Control("b"), new Control("c") };
            var list3 = new List<Control> { new Control("a"), new Control("b"), new Control("c") };

            foreach (var ctrl in GetList(list1, list2, list3).Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("a"))) {
                ctrl.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rr, gg, bb);
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Control> GetList (params IEnumerable<Control>[] controls) {
            return controls.SelectMany(x => x);
        }
    }
}
```